# Shortest possible 1/4" male to 1/4" female adapter or cable

Tags: electric-guitar, equipment, cable

[image]

My Line6 G10 juts into my stomach due to the angle of my guitar's output jack, making it very uncomfortable to play. I can turn it the other direction, but...

[image]

...the molding of the guitar there keeps it literally a 1/4" short of fully inserting. Notice also there's a tiny metal button at the base of the Line6 G10—that has to be depressed in order for the unit to be on.

1. I'm having no luck finding 1/4" to 1/4" male-female adapters (similar to 1/4" to 1/8" headphone adapters), which makes sense. Why on Earth would anyone need that.
2. I thought I'd settle for a patch cable, just looping it around my strap, but I also can't find a short male-female patch cable! Again, I think my application is far too limited.
3. I tried L-joints. After the right angle they still jut into my side.

Aside from 2x adapters or a patch cable plus and adapter (which keep making the aesthetics worse and worse), can anyone think of solution or know of a product that can help me?

Comment: Make one up yourself. Just needs a short piece of coax, a male jack and an in-line female. 5 minutes!

Answer (score 4):

Definitely make one yourself or have someone make it for you.  Some additional considerations:

Maybe obvious: If you have an old patch/instrument cord with only one good end, you can cut off and discard the bad end.  You have just saved yourself the trouble of soldering the male end.  Strip the cut end to solder to a female connector

Instead of making it as short as possible, consider making it just long enough to attach the transmitter to your strap with a hook-and-loop fastener.

It's hard to tell on the photo the position of the power button.  Make sure the female connector is wide enough to depress it when connected.  (There is some variation in diameter between products.)

If you don't know how to make one and don't know someone who can do it, there are online shops that will do it, like [Redco](https://www.redco.com/Custom-Cable.html?cableid=TAPHH6).

Comment: I had the same thought of making it long enough to attach to the strap. Otherwise it would just be dangling from the instrument.

Answer (score 3):

Get one made up, or get the soldering iron out yourself.

I have to say, that's got to be one of the most awkward-looking jack sockets to try do anything non-standard with, but you've the choice of it being as short as you can get the cable whilst still being able to unscrew the barrel to reach the solder points… eg…

[image]

…or long enough you could drop it round the strap holder, so it doesn't get caught on anything.

<sup>Yeah, I know that's an XLR, it's just the only DIY micro-cable I own;)</sup>

I suppose you could get all medieval on it & chummel a slot into the functionally pointless bit of bodywork to the right ;)

Answer (score 2):

Switchcraft makes some adaptors that can be screwed together to make the adaptor you are looking for. The first is a Switchcraft 44X and it can screw together with a Switchcraft 33-2x. Both can be ordered online. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a mono connection, why not use a stereo/mono adapter?  Should work fine, and probably the shortest possible.  Hosa GPP-290 is one example.

Comment: Brilliant, I've ordered one. I needed an adapter that does _something_ or it wouldn't exist, but a something that does _nothing_ since I just needed an extender. Will follow up.

Comment: I'm sorry to shoot this idea down, but I think you'll find that when you plug it in all the way, you'll be shorting your signal to ground because the sleeve will be making contact with the ring (hot) contact inside the adaptor. You might be able to avoid this by only plugging in to the first click, but then the little pushbutton switch would have nothing to press against to engage. Just trying to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and cheapest solution would be to let the *socket* protrude a centimetre from the guitar. Not sure what model of jack Stranberg uses, but many guitars use the type that has a screw profile all over, with two nuts to hold it in place. In that case, you could just release the inside nut and tighten again with the outside nut, and pronto, you'll have it pointing out enough. If it doesn't work with the stock jack, maybe replace it with another one.

If you can't get that to work, then I'd solder my own short patch cable for the job, or indeed solder a cable right to the G10.